# In PHP how to search div and add wrapper container divs

Tags: php

In PHP I want to search div and the images coming inside div need to add wrapping divs, like

```
<div id="div1"><img src="test1.jpg" /></div><div id="div2"><img src="test1.jpg" /><img src="test2.jpg" /></div>
```

Whatever images are coming inside `<div id="div2">` I need to reformat, like

```
<div id="div2"><div id="imageContainer"><img src="test1.jpg" /></div><div id="imageContainer"><img src="test2.jpg" /></div></div>
```

Thanks,
coder

Comment: Do you mean you want to do this using a php editor of some sort?

Comment: An ID attribute used in HTML should uniquely identify the element.

Comment: I am creating templates in wordpress in some areas design is complicated and lots of divs are coming so without confusing client, using the code I need to add some divs

Answer (score 0):

best practice is to use an XML Parser, like

[DOM](http://php.net/manual/de/ref.domxml.php)

like this you can get a value:

```
function getXpathValues(&$dom, $expr) {
$xpth = $dom->xpath_new_context();
    $xnode = xpath_eval($xpth,$expr);
    if (isset ($xnode->nodeset[0])) {
        $firstnode = $xnode->nodeset[0];
        $children = $firstnode->children();
        $value = $children[0]->content;
    return $value;
}
        else return Null;
}
```

Usage :

```
$dom = domxml_open_file('pear.rss');
echo $this->getXpathValues($dom, "//channel/title");
```

taken form here:
[php manual](http://ch.php.net/manual/de/function.xpath-new-context.php#32428)

to really insert new elements go for this:
[xsl: for more complexity](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xsl.php)
or loop the elements, add the child to a new one (div imageContainer),
remove the childs, and add the new element

or really the simplest - just do a string replace ..

Comment: thanks remy can you give example, I don't have much experience in php

Comment: I don't see why you would use an xml parser. There is a much simplier way to do this.

Comment: maybe a too quick look .. just the proper (overheaded) way ;)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest ways is to use preg_replace();

You search for the img tag and then you place a div around it

```
<?php preg_replace("/\[(img .*?)\]/","<div class='div2'><$1></div>", $content); ?>
```

But you say you are creating a wordpress template.. is the code, you posted above, submitted through a form or in the theme files?